# "There was an error importing this build" on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

For some reason the build that I uploaded to iTunes Connect shows the following message:

> There was an error importing this build.

There is no additional information about the error nor searching for the issue helped. Can anyone point me why this kind of error occurs?

Comment: same here - going to try resubmitting my build...

Comment: @shi11i already did it but same outcome.

Comment: I was deploying for 9.0. I changed that to 8.3 and it went through.

Comment: @shi11i : did you find the fix for it?

Comment: @jaym yeah deploying to 8.3 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! in my case it was Apple's issue, multiple people were facing the same issue, not it's fixed.